# How to split the below string with delimiter inside value

Tags: java, delimiter

I have following string with delimiter `*`

```
String temp=""Test1*Test2"*Test3*Test4";
```

require like this:

```
"Test1*Test2"
Test3
Test4
```

`split(\\*)` is not working it has given result like this:

```
"Test1
Test2"
Test3
Test4
```

Can you please suggest which time of delimiter should i used to split the string as required.

Comment: please be more specific. what is the expected result? what do you get (your phrase like it is formatted is unclear how much string you get)

Comment: `temp.split("*");` doesn't work?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]. Use the [edit] link to improve your *question* - do not add more information via comments. Thanks!

Comment: AntonH's response should work.

Comment: Will your substring always start and end with quotes if it includes the quote character?  As in `Te”st1*Te”st2*Test3*Test4` will never appear?  Replace all delimiters with commas and all commas with your delimiter, and use an CSV parser.  Then, change the surviving commas/delimiters back.

Comment: ho you mean, ignoring quoted parts of a string? this would be incredibly difficult to achieve with regexp... You need a loop and a complex logic, eg. 1) building substrings when you are out of quotes looking for stars, and 2) when you are inside quotes, looking for the final quote.

Answer (score 1):

The split() method is great when it’s easy to write a regular expression to match the delimiters. 
For example you can easily split a string along commas: String.split(",");.

But the method is terrible when the delimiters can occur in the split content.

A common job is to split a string along commas, except when those commas appear in double quotes. 
Such a string might be a line in a CSV file.

In such cases, it is much easier to write a regex that matches the content you want to keep in the array, 
and use Matcher.find() instead of String.split().

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String regex = "\"[^\"]*\"|[^\\*]+";
    String temp = "\"Test1*Test2\"*Test3*Test4";         
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);
    Matcher m = p.matcher(temp);
    while(m.find()){
        System.out.println(m.group());
    }
}
```

The regex matches a pair of double quotes with anything except double quotes between them, or a series of characters that don’t include an asterisk (*).

Answer (score 0):

String[] csvRawData = line.split(delimiter);

```
            for(int i = 0; i < csvRawData.length; i++) {
                if(csvRawData[i].startsWith("\"")) {
                    if(csvRawData[i+1].endsWith("\"")) {
                        csvRawData[i] = csvRawData[i] + "*" + csvRawData[i+1];                          
                        csvRawData = (String[]) ArrayUtils.remove(csvRawData, 1);                   
                    }
                }
            }
```